# How to undo a merge (without commit)?

Tags: svn, merge, commit, undo

I just did an `svn merge` to merge changes from the trunk to a branch:

```
$ svn merge -r328:HEAD file:///home/user/svn/repos/proj/trunk .
--- Merging r388 through r500 into '.':
A    foo
A    bar
   C baz1
   C baz2
U    duh
[...]
```

But there were too many conflicts, so I'd like to undo that.

One way to do that is to commit and then merge back. But I can't commit because of the conflicts. What's the best way to undo in that case?

Answer (score 125):

Revert recursively from the top of your working copy:

`svn revert -R .`

You will need to manually delete the files that were added. As in after reverting, the files added will remain on disk but they will be in a non-tracked state ("? foo")

Comment: This command will also revert any local modifications that existed before you did the merge though correct?

Comment: @NeilMonday true, but then you shouldn't merge into a working copy with local, non-merge-related changes anyway.

Answer (score 7):

As long as you haven't commited, you can always do a revert to undo all your changes.

Comment: Hmm, just `svn revert .` didn't do anything.

Comment: OK, then you should resolve everything first, then do the revert.

Comment: ...and like @rq said, don't forget the -R flag to do the revert recursively.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same situation, also I had some other changes which I didn't wanted to lose.
So, instead of full recursive revert just `svn revert` for the conflicted items was good for me

```
svn revert baz1 baz2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't committed the changes, you can do TortoiseSVN -> click Revert and select the Uncommitted changes and revert

If you have committed and if you want to Undo the changes then SVN logs -> select the revision, right click and then Revert the changes of that particular revision. then commit the code

Answer (score -11):

Just do `svn resolve` on all conflicts anyway and commit:

```
$ svn resolved baz1
$ svn resolved baz2
$ svn ci -m "oops. bad merge. will revert."
Transmitting file data ......
Committed revision 501.
```

Then, officially undo it by merging  back to where it was:

```
$ svn merge -r501:500
--- Reverse-merging r319 into '.':
[...]
```

That's it, the merge has been undone in the directory. Now commit that too:

```
$ svn ci -m "bad merge has been undone"
Transmitting file data ......
Committed revision 502.
```

The advantage over the `svn revert -R .` method is that the files that were added are all properly removed.

Comment: You don't really want to be puking conflict markers into your repository's *permanent* history, do you!? Yuck.

Comment: @LakshmanPrasad If someone checks out/updates in between these two commits the conflict markers will end up in someone's working copy...